# django I get a TemplateDoesNotExist when loading a page

Tags: python, django

My directories are structured in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKotf.png)

I don't know why i'm getting the error. Please assist. Let me know if you need more info.

[Screenshot of the ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbNA3.png)

Comment: `my_app` vs `myapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directory on template myapp, seams the url is searching on my_app template on the error image you shared.
try using one, make sure the directory is the same name as the app name which you already did. 
 seems the error is from the view rendering make sure its same name myapp

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much! You're correct. The name was wrong.

Comment: You are welcome, all make same mistakes at a point or another.